# Deneb format value with two decimal places and prefix

Tags: d3.js, powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

Is it possible to format a value in Deneb (I'm using Vega-Lite) to change 1.000 to "1k" or 1.000.000 "1M" with the addition, that the value has maximum two decimal places
...
"text": {
"field": "Value",
"type": "quantitative",
"aggregate": "sum",
"format": ",~s"
},
...

For example: 1.789.979,32323 to 1,79M

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
"format": ",.3~s"
Or
"format": ",.4~s"
etc
```

Here’s a quick rundown of how the SI number formatting works:

```
1.  1e-24: “y” (yocto)
2.  1e-21: “z” (zepto)
3.  1e-18: “a” (atto)
4.  1e-15: “f” (femto)
5.  1e-12: “p” (pico)
6.  1e-9: “n” (nano)
7.  1e-6: “µ” (micro)
8.  1e-3: “m” (milli)
9.  1: (no prefix, just the number)
10. 1e3: “k” (kilo)
11. 1e6: “M” (mega)
12. 1e9: “G” (giga)
13. 1e12: “T” (tera)
14. 1e15: “P” (peta)
15. 1e18: “E” (exa)
16. 1e21: “Z” (zetta)
17. 1e24: “Y” (yotta)
```

When you use the “s” format in Vega-Lite, numbers will be automatically scaled to fit one of these SI prefixes. For example:

```
•   1000 would be formatted as 1k
•   1500000 would be formatted as 1.5M
•   0.002 would be formatted as 2m
```

Here’s a brief breakdown:

```
•   s: Formats numbers using SI-prefix notation.
•   ~: Removes trailing zeros in the significant figures.
```

Let’s look at some examples to clarify:

```
•   With the format .3s:
•   1500000 would be formatted as 1.50M
•   1000 would be formatted as 1.00k
•   With the format .3~s:
•   1500000 would be formatted as 1.5M (the trailing zero is removed)
•   1000 would be formatted as 1k (both trailing zeros are removed)
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Deneb doc](https://deneb-viz.github.io/formatting#power-bi-custom-formatter) for using [Power BI's custom format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-custom-format-strings), which are so much better than the D3/Vega syntax.

```json
    "x": {
      "field": "$ Sales",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "format": "$#0,,.00M",
        "formatType": "pbiFormat"
      }
    }
```

The D3/Vega syntax isn't bad if you only need K or M and not both. Here's the example for K and 1 decimal place.

```json
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.b/1000", "as": "b"}
  ],
  ...
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "b (in thousands)"}}
  ...
        "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "format": ",.1~f"}
```

[image]
You can read more about the [D3 formatting syntax here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/main/README.md#format).

If you need an "Auto" format that chooses K or M depending on the number, you can use DAX to create the value as text and pass that to Deneb.

```
Format Actual = 
VAR _number = SUM(KPIsDATA[Actual])
VAR _digits = 2
RETURN IF( ABS(_number) >= 1000000000, FORMAT(_number, "0,,," & IF(_digits > 0, ".", "") & REPT("0",_digits) & "B"),
           IF( ABS(_number) >= 1000000, FORMAT(_number, "0,," & IF(_digits > 0, ".", "") & REPT("0",_digits) & "M"),
               IF( ABS(_number) >= 1000, FORMAT(_number, "0," & IF(_digits > 0, ".", "") & REPT("0",_digits) & "K"),           
                   FORMAT(_number, "0" & IF(_digits > 0, ".", "") & REPT("0",_digits) )
               )
           )
       )
```

For more on this, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212435/is-there-a-method-to-pass-the-formatting-selection-made-in-the-powerbi-menu-to-a/75222657#75222657).

To do Auto formats in Vega, try this:

```json
"transform": [
    {"calculate": "if(abs(datum.b)>1000000000, round(datum.b/10000000)/100+'B',if(abs(datum.b)>1000000, round(datum.b/10000)/100+'M',if(abs(datum.b)>1000, round(datum.b/10)/100+'k',datum.b)))", "as": "b-label"}
  ],
```